# SVN to Git migration issue

Tags: git, svn, github, svn2git

I am in a stage of migrating the source code data from Subversion to Git.

I was successful in migrating `29000` commits in to Git and after that the process get hung and found the below issue.

used `svn2git htt://svnrepopath --verbose`

```
 RA layer request failed: REPORT request failed on
 '/svn/FULL_2/!svn/vcc/default': REPORT of
 '/svn/FULL_2/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read chunk size: Secure
 iln-DT.sc.cpa2biz.local) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm
 line 290
```

We have 65000 commits in Subversion that should migrate into Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I vaguely remember encountering this exact error trying to import around 100,000 SVN commits into Git. The trick is to do this in batches. I created a shell script that started at SVN commit 1, imported 1,000 commits, then stopped. It wrote the last commit number to a text file, so that the next time the shell script started up, it incremented the commit number by one, and imported 1,000 more commits. I had this running as a cron job over a weekend and it proved to be very stable.

Since the shell script stayed at my last job, these are the `git svn` commands that were used:

```
git svn init --stdlayout url/to/svn/repository
```

Once the Git-SVN repository was created, the cron job just ran:

```
git svn fetch -r 1:1000 --authors-file=/path/to/svn-to-git/authors.txt
... some time later...
git svn fetch -r 1001:2000 --authors-file=/path/to/svn-to-git/authors.txt
... some time later...
git svn fetch -r 2001:3000 --authors-file=/path/to/svn-to-git/authors.txt
...
```

Comment: Could you please let me know the script that you have used earlier.

Comment: @Balu: I wish I could. It was at a previous company. Let me do a little research to at least find the `git svn` commands I used.